# ASP Classic & IIS 7: Make error-pages mail me with the errors

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

I know ASP, JMail and such.
I know where to edit my HTML error pages in IIS 7, but i want to take it one step further:

How do I a ASP error page where it state something like "Error, the customer support were contacted, please try again later."

And then it send me an e-mail with the detailed debugging-information about the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the instructions from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224070 and [Custom Errors on IIS 7.0 and Classic ASP](http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/custom-errors-error-pages-500-100-asp-classic-asp-and-iis-7-0)
First one shows a detailed error information to the guests when an error occurs.
You can modify that to sends an e-mail message that contains detailed error information.
Second one is to configuring custom error page in IIS7.

Comment: make sure you also set the appropriate response details on the right "Edit Feature Settings".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific aspx error page, you could add the code for sending mail in the code behind, or you could use [Application_Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx) from global.asax.

Comment: Application_Error requires an ASP.NET application, for ASP classic one has to handle IIS7 server events.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use .Net and ASP.NET variant of ASP then you can [handle Application_Error event](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JcGlobalErrorHandling.aspx) and send the information you need using STMP-class from System.Net. You can customize your own error page by manually [editing your web.config file](http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/10/03/iis7-enabling-custom-error-pages.aspx).

If you are bound to the classical ASP and don't use .Net on server side, then you need to handle the error event directly on the server. You can [read here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/366/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework/) how you develop handlers for IIS events using .Net.

Comment: Where is the useful information regarding classic asp here? All you seem to be saying is "Use asp.net"